# How to check if entire string matches regular expression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a function in javascript which checks if entire string matches some regular expression

`'00'.match(/^0|([1-9][0-9]*)$/g)` for example returns `['0']`

I know I can simply check if the matched part is equal to the string, but I'm just curious if such function already exists

edit:

`'01'.match(/^0|1$/g)` returns `['0', '1']`
and `'01'.match(/^(0|1)$/g)` returns null as expected.

I though | has precedence over ^ or $. Can someone explain what `/^0|1$/g` actually matches?

Comment: `/^0|1$/g` matches a `0` at the beginning of the string or a `1` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you exacty want to achieve. I suppose you want to match eiter zero or a number, not beginning with zero. Then try this:

```
'00'.match(/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/g)
```

This does not match '00', but all the other cases.